# JSON Ajax data issue

Tags: c#, javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, json

I have found the issue however my solution does not work.  The variables d0 and d1 get populated but after the code creates and splices the array storelocations. Therefore, I get an error that d0 and d1 is undefined. Any solutions? thx for the help

Javascript:

```
    $(function () {


        $.get("/Map/GetJsonData", function (data) {
            storeLocations = [];
            var d0 = data[0].Delay;
            var d1 = data[1].Delay;


        });

        var storeLocations = new Array();
        storeLocations.splice(storeLocations.length, 0, d0);
        storeLocations.splice(storeLocations.length - 1, 0, d1);


}
```

Comment: _"However, the data is not being passed"_ - And what actually does happen? If you add `console.log(data)` as the first line of your callback function what does it show?

Comment: Make sure `Clinics` is filled up correctly or are you missing something on url (may be ../Map/GetJsonData), try using `$.get("/Map/GetJsonData", function (data) {})`, this may not solve your issue but saves some cycles.

Comment: if I add document.write(d0); inside the $.get it prints out the correct information.

Answer (score 0):

Take these debugging steps:

1. First of all, call your action via browser. See if there is any result showing as JSON or not. Simply enter the full URL, like `http://domain/Map/GetJsonData`
2. If you think you really have data in your database, but data is not shown in the browser, then try to debug through Visual Studio. Breakpoints are to rescue here.
3. If you get data back via browser, then try simple `$.get` method of jQuery. Even test `$.ajax` with parameters.

Comment: Good response here. Just to add for user2138160 - F12 in most browsers will bring up the developer tools which will allow you to debug javascript fairly well. If you are using Firefox, you may want to download Firebug for debugging also.